# Bootstrap Modal with Jquery on Rails 6

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a list of items in the index page, and I added a button on every product, so the show action, instead of going to a show page opens a modal with the show info.

For that, I created a partial to render the show info, but the modal is not loading. In the console the error is pointing to the `show.erb` file and not the render.

This is my index page:

```rb
<tbody>
  <% @shopifyproducts.each do |shopifyproduct| %>
    <tr>
      <td><img height=75 src=<%= shopifyproduct.image %>  /></td>
      <td><%= shopifyproduct.sku %></td>
      <td><%= shopifyproduct.title %></td>
      <td>$ <%= shopifyproduct.price %></td>
      <td><span>
        <input class="form" type="text" name="dwtoys" form="myform" value=<%=shopifyproduct.inventory.to_i%> />
          <%= link_to 'Add', shopifyproduct,  {:remote => true, 'data-toggle' =>  "modal", 'data-target' =>
         '#exampleModal', class: 'btn btn-primary btn-lg'}  %>         
      </td>

      <td><%= link_to 'Show', shopifyproduct %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_shopifyproduct_path(shopifyproduct) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', shopifyproduct, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</tbody>
```

This is my **_show.html.erb** page

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <%= @shopifyproduct.title %>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my show controller:

```
def show
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js
  end
end
```

And finally this is the `application.js` file:

```
$("#myModal").find(".modal-content").html("<%= j (render 'show') %>");
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    $('#myInput').trigger('focus')
```

If instead of using the render, I add the modal to the index page, it works, but no matter which product I click, it always displays the info of the first product. Thats why I'm trying to render into a partial with the data of that product only.

Comment: i really need some help here, cause i dont know what else to try...

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle unicity for each modal.

Try this :

```
<%= link_to 'Add', shopifyproduct,  {:remote => true, 'data-toggle' =>  "modal", 'data-target' =>
         '#exampleModal-<%= shopifyproduct.id %>', class: 'btn btn-primary btn-lg'}  %>
```

and each shopifyproduct should have its own modal :

```
<% @shopifyproducts.each do |shopifyproduct| %>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal-<%= shopifyproduct.id %>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <%= shopifyproduct.title %>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Help me understand a little, in my code, the index page already has a loop through prodcuts, why you add a second one? this is supposed to go in the index page?